# How to install Apple iOS on qemu

Tags: ios, emulation, qemu, device-emulation

Qemu supports ARM (and many other platforms). So, what do I need (besides installation media) to install Apple iOS on qemu? Are there ways to create iOS image suitable for Qemu?

**Update:**

Apple A4 = Cortex-A8 + PowerVR SGX535 
Apple A5 = Cortex-A9 MPCore + PowerVR SGX543MP2

Both Cortexes use ARM v7 instruction set which is supported by Qemu. The problem is that:

- iOS doesn't support any of video-cards that can be emulated by Qemu
- Qemu can't emulate PowerVR GPU.

Comment: I doubt it. I believe there are a whole lot of hardware interactions that the OS uses to confirm that it's on an Apple device. I think this is what makes Jailbreaking such a hassle.

Comment: another link to use OpenGLES 2.0 emulator
http://forums.arm.com/index.php?/topic/14923-can-we-support-virtual-framebuffer-on-opengles-emulator-20/ good idea to search in google "qemu support 3D acceleration" http://lists.gnu.org/archive/cgi-bin/namazu.cgi?query=3d&submit=Search&idxname=qemu-devel

Comment: I came here looking for the ability to directly emulate ios using qemu because it would be much preferable to the way I currently do it which is emulate BigSur using qemu and then run ios using xCode on BigSur.  It is incredibly slow and cumbersome but it works on my Ryzen 7 lenovo running Arch Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QEMU does not emulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU#Features) Apple A4/A5 architecture.

Answer (score 2):

there are libraries to emulate  SGX

at http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-utilities.asp

maybe they can be used to make a hardware module for qemu

also there is some development that was doing on the gpu in the mailing list

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2010-10/msg02073.html

---

https://wiki.linaro.org/Platform/DevPlatform/QemuOpenGLES

http://planet.linaro.org/tag/meego/

---

https://wiki.linaro.org/Platform/DevPlatform/QemuOpenGLES

http://planet.linaro.org/tag/meego/

Answer (score 2):

This is old, but still good question. I found new answer to it. Try [qemu for iOS](https://github.com/nvsio/qemu-ios) on github.

Comment: There is no documentation on that. Have you been able to port that into qemu?

Comment: This is really old github project without documentation, but it proves, that simulate ARM is possible.